# Use Master dataframe to aggregate regression loop using rbind

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, bind

All, I'm very new to R, and can't find anything in the existing questions database that fits my exact issue. I'm running a loop of several regressions (200), and am trying to bind the results/coefficients into a single dataframe that I can export to Excel, with one set of headers.  All variables in each regression are identical.  The regression part of my loop looks like,

```
getreg<-OutChg~USInput
stepreg<-lm(getreg,data=mydata)
```

I'm trying use a "master" dataframe to bind everything together, such as,

```
master<-data.frame()
master<-rbind(master,stepreg$coefficients)
```

But I get the response `Error in stepreg$coefficients : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`.  Ideally, I'd like to have something where I don't even have to define `master<-data.frame()`.

Any advice is much appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: The error is most likely due to the fact that `stepreg <- lm(getreg,data=mydata)` hasn't been run yet when you're calling `stepreg$coefficients`, so I'd suggest first checking that it has (for example, if I take an unassigned variable name (e.g. `xyz`) and call `xyz$coefficients`, I produce your error). Also, it'd be easier to give you an efficient solution if you could share what your loop currently looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `getreg <- as.formula(OutChg ~ USInput)` or just put that in the for the `lm()` function. 
If you use `str(stepreg)` you will probably find that it is not a list but some other data type (in this case an atomic vector).
In order to use `rbind()` the variable "master" has to exist (as something)

Comment: Kevin, thank you for your reply.  Your solution worked well (using as.formula).  When I try to bind a column with the regression name, however, I get an error that says `cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'list'`.  The code that I'm trying to use is 

   `y<-names(Regression1)
    stepreg<-lm(as.formula(OutChg~USInput),data=newdata)
    sign<-cbind(stepreg$coefficients,y))
    mastersign<-rbind(mastersign,sign)`

Any thoughts as to how to bind the name of the third column onto the dataframe that's accumulating the regression coefficients?  Thank you again!

Comment: @JoeJackson1234 The `cbind()` is not doing what (I think) you want. It will create two rows (one for each coefficient) and then add a column for "y". I always find it helpful to examine the variables to see if they contain what I **think** they contain.

Comment: Kevin, that's actually what I want it to do!  An extra column for the Y variable titles.  It keep returning the `cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'list'` issue, though...any ideas?

Thank you again for all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
datandfit <- function(x) {

  USInput <- rnorm(100, 0, 5)
  OutChg <- USInput*5 + 10 + rnorm(100, 0, 5)
  mydata <- data.table(USInput, OutChg)
  stepreg <- lm(OutChg ~ USInput, data = mydata)
  data.table(t(stepreg$coefficients))

}
```

This will generate some random data, fit a model to it, and return a data.table of the results. You would skip the first three lines of the function, since you would already have data. Then, you can `lapply` over the function, which will return a list of 200 `data.table`s, and use `rbindlist` to combine them all into one `data.table`.

```
rbindlist(lapply(1:200, datandfit))

     (Intercept)  USInput
  1:    9.979968 4.909842
  2:   10.086159 5.083225
  3:   10.285307 4.873432
  4:   10.457751 4.905266
  5:    9.108176 5.005555
 ---                     
196:   10.715356 4.846002
197:    9.938905 4.966180
198:    9.968473 5.073163
199:   10.098703 5.065169
200:    9.538539 4.946085
```

Answer (score 1):

All, I finally figured this out! As a new user and non-programmer, figuring out how the different R objects work together is cumbersome, but using master<-list() before doing any of the "binding" got it to work...took me a minute or two to realize I can't have the loop designate the master as a list every time or it erases previous aggregation, too...thanks all for your help!